# How do I convert the Amplitude from Power/Amplitude spectral density?

Tags: fft, discrete-signals, frequency-spectrum, time-series, spectrum-estimation

I recently started working on PSD of seismic signals. PSD signal can be expressed in 2 ways. One in ($PSD=g^2/Hz$) and other in $PSD=((meter/sec.^2)^2/Hz)$ and $ASD = \sqrt(PSD)$.

More details have found in the link https://ucum.org/ucum.html#section-Special-Units-on-non-ratio-Scales

I want to find the amplitude of the spectrum in $(meter.second)^2/Hz$  from the expression of PSD. I don't clearly understand how to convert. Can anyone please provide explanations?